# read multiple set of rows from excel and put it in different file

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, data-analysis

I have below like data in one excel file. I have to separate the data into a different file.

```
id  name    fname   lname
1   sample  sample  sample
2   sample  sample  sample
3   sample  sample  sample
4   sample  sample  sample


id  firstmark   secondmark  thirdmark
1   23  23  23
2   23  23  23
3   23  23  23
4   23  23  23
5   23  23  23
6   23  23  23
7   23  23  23
8   23  23  23
```

my expected output will be 
user excel file

```
id  name    fname   lname
1   sample  sample  sample
2   sample  sample  sample
3   sample  sample  sample
4   sample  sample  sample
```

mark excel file

```
id  firstmark   secondmark  thirdmark
1   23  23  23
2   23  23  23
3   23  23  23
4   23  23  23
5   23  23  23
6   23  23  23
7   23  23  23
8   23  23  23
```

The number of rows may vary upon the data.

How to separate the contents

Comment: One way would be to read the data in as a single dataframe and use filtering on "column headers" to create new dataframes.

Comment: Have you looked at this Q and A? : https://stackoverflow.com/q/51283963/4961700

Answer (score 0):

you could get the rownum where the `id` column equals 'id' and then split it according to the rownum.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('my_file.xlsx')
new_df_loc = df[df.id=='id'].tolist()[0]

df1, df2 = df.iloc[:new_df_loc], df.iloc[new_df_loc:]
df1.dropna(how='all', inplace=True)  # remove null rows
df2.columns = df2.iloc[0]  # change headers
```