# Excel VBA: pull specific worksheet from different files into existing workbook and change name

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to VBA and am trying to do the following below

For example: 
Worksheets' name is "Sheet1" I need to pull this specific sheet from many different files in different folders into an existing Workbook "Workbook A".

- Paste the new sheets as values
- Unprotect the sheet
- Then rename these new sheets based on a cell value's "A2" first 4 values

Doing all this without altering the existing worksheets in Workbook A. Just applying this to the newly integrated sheets "Sheet1".

Comment: Have you searched on here for any possible Q and A that does something similar? And I only ask you ask I know there are some... You should show some effort as this is not a "free coding service" where you post what you want and collect 24h later...

Comment: Try recording a macro and see what they gives you, then edit your question with it.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ - please do read this document properly. It will help you ask a much better question and in return you will receive a much better answer.

Comment: Have look at : https://stackoverflow.com/q/51283963/4961700

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this code to pull in the worksheets, however the link to the folders do not alwys function especially if I change it.   ChDir ("\C:Test") It also takes a long time opening and then closing files. And asking for updates to links everytime a workbook is opened.

Dim DataName As String
    Dim DataWB As Workbook
    Dim File As String
    Dim MasterWB As Workbook
    Dim MScnt As Integer
    Dim Snr As Integer

```
'Find out number of sheets in Master
Set MasterWB = ActiveWorkbook
MScnt = MasterWB.Sheets.Count

'Switch to folder containing data workbooks
'Use path from master for now
ChDir ("\\C:Test")

'Find al xlsx workbooks in folder
File = Dir("*.xlsx")
While File <> ""
    Debug.Print "Processing file " & File
    'Do not process yourself
    If InStr(File, MasterWB.Name) = 0 Then
        'Open data workbook
        Set DataWB = Workbooks.Open(File, xlUpdateLinksNever, True)
        DataWB.Activate
        'Catch missing input sheet
        On Error Resume Next
        Snr = 0
        Snr = Sheets("2. Hours Reconciliation").Index
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Snr > 0 Then
            Sheets(Snr).Copy After:=MasterWB.Sheets(1)
            MasterWB.Activate
            'Rename added sheet; use data wb name for now
        End If
        MasterWB.Activate
        DataWB.Close False
    End If
    'Next file
    File = Dir()
Wend
```

End Sub